# Is there a way to have all open programs restored after a restart?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to have all open programs restored after a restart exactly where their open windows were on-screen before the restart?

I have about 22 programs and/or files open, each day all day — this is the way I work most efficiently, flitting between them all constantly.  I like to backup and restart every night, but it is a pain to have to initiate them all one-by-one the next morning into their unique positions for quick, easy, one-click access.

Is there a solution now?  Or is one coming in the future?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Is suspend to memory not good enough? Or even hibernation? It will keep things exactly as they are for you when you come back.

Comment: As he says, he backs up and restarts each night. The restart will wipe anything there.

Answer (score -1):

[Twinsplay](http://www.zinstall.com/products/twinsplay/download-twinsplay) Professional Edition is the only software out there that can come close to what you are asking.  It is not perfect but that is the closest without writing some custom software.